# MariaDB Running out of Memory

Tags: mariadb, out-of-memory

Our MariaDB server keeps running out of memory every few days and I'm out of ideas on what could be causing it. We are running on 10.11.5 version with Galera replication and a ProxySQL middle layer for failovers that is also connection pooling. Currently MariaDB is taking up around 24GB of memory of our 32GB server. We've switched our malloc library to tcmalloc gperftools 2.6.1 because the default one was reported to possibly have a memory leak and it helped a little bit, but memory still increases just at a slower rate now.

I'm not sure what is causing it to take so much memory as the innodb_buffer_pool is at the default value (I'd love to increase it but that just causes the server to run out of memory quicker). The connection pooling keeps 300 connections open which is quite a bit, but with our configuration a connection should only take about 19MB of memory so 19MB*300 is only 5GB and with a max_connected value of 883 that would be 16.8GB which is still less than the 24GBs in use right now. Is my logic incorrect and these connections are causing more memory use than I'm aware of? Is there a way to check how much memory the table or thread caches are using? Is replication causing this?

[SHOW STATUS](https://pastebin.com/Dm91kn3T)

[SHOW VARIABLES](https://pastebin.com/1FfmqidZ)

**Configs**

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema=ON
event_scheduler=ON

max_connections = 5000

# 0 is recommended for SSD
innodb_flush_neighbors=0

# Recommended to be small if not using MyISAM indexes (default 1G)
key_buffer_size=10M

[mariadb]
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error_log.log
log_warnings=4
slow_query_log=1
long_query_time = 5
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/slow_query.log

# Lower Connection Sleep Time
wait_timeout = 600
```

Comment: Pastebin says: "Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation. If this paste belongs to you, please login to Pastebin to view it."

Comment: "max_connections = 5000" seems not to be inline with your question?

Comment: @Luuk I've updated the Pastebin to public, hopefully that allows you to see it.

Comment: I am still getting the "Forbidden (#403)"

Comment: @Luuk it needed moderation, maybe it was too large. I've split them out into separate links and it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.11.5-MariaDB-log
- 32 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 3d 17:53:38
- 217 Queries/sec : 30.8 Questions/sec

---

**The More Important Issues:**

Recommended changes to settings:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20G   # This is probably the most important
long_query_time = 2   # and keep an eye on the slowlog
```

How many tables do you have?  (cf table_open_cache, etc)

Be sure to test for deadlocks (at COMMIT, etc); you seem to have a several.

Consider moving away from latin1 to utf8mb4.  (The conversion won't be trivial.)

SHOW CREATE TABLE about once a second -- Why?

It seems 'wrong' to do more SETs than SELECTs.

One-third of connections hit Aborted_clients -- I don't have a recommendation.

Lots of temp tables be ing used; ponder whether things could be improved.

If your disk is SSD (not HDD),

```
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_io_capacity_max = 3000
max_connections = 1000   # unless you really need more _simultaneously_
```

---

**Details and other observations:**

`( Key_reads + Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) = (0 + 0 + 64423401 + 516159 + 9239 + 516159) / 323618 = 202 /sec` -- IOPs?
-- If the hardware can handle it, set innodb_io_capacity (now 200) to about this value.

`( ( Key_reads + Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) / innodb_io_capacity / Uptime ) = ( 0 + 0 + 64423401 + 516159 + 9239 + 516159 ) / 200 / 323618 = 101.1%` -- This *may* be a metric indicating what innodb_io_capacity is set reasonably.
-- Increase innodb_io_capacity (now 200) if the hardware can handle it.

`( Opened_tables ) = 757402 / 323618 = 2.3 /sec` -- Frequency of opening Tables
-- increase table_open_cache (now 2000)

`( Opened_table_definitions ) = 1198434 / 323618 = 3.7 /sec` -- Frequency of opening .frm files
-- Increase table_definition_cache (now 400) and/or table_open_cache (now 2000).

`( Table_open_cache_overflows ) = 415526 / 323618 = 1.3 /sec`
-- May need to increase table_open_cache (now 2000)

`( Table_open_cache_misses ) = 1079077 / 323618 = 3.3 /sec`
-- May need to increase table_open_cache (now 2000)

`( Table_open_cache_misses / (Table_open_cache_hits + Table_open_cache_misses) ) = 1,079,077 / (10428081 + 1079077) = 9.4%` -- Effectiveness of table_open_cache.
-- Increase table_open_cache (now 2000) and check table_open_cache_instances (now 8).

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 128M` -- InnoDB Data + Index cache
-- 128M (an old default) is woefully small.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 128 / 32768M = 0.39%` -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool
-- Set to about 70% of available RAM. (To low is less efficient; too high risks swapping.)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,536` -- innodb_lru_scan_depth is a very poorly named variable. A better name would be innodb_free_page_target_per_buffer_pool. It is a number of pages InnoDB tries to keep free in each buffer pool instance to speed up read and page creation operations.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- When flushing, use this many IOPs.
-- Reads could be slugghish or spiky. Use 2000 if using SSD drive.

`( innodb_io_capacity_max / innodb_io_capacity ) = 2,000 / 200 = 10` -- Capacity: max/plain
-- Recommend 2. Max should be about equal to the IOPs your I/O subsystem can handle. (If the drive type is unknown 2000/200 may be a reasonable pair.)

`( Innodb_pages_written / Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests ) = 516,159 / 2836528 = 18.2%` -- Write requests that had to hit disk
-- Check innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 134217728)

`( (Innodb_buffer_pool_reads + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed) ) = ((64423401 + 516159) ) / 323618 = 200 /sec` -- InnoDB I/O
-- Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 134217728)?

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 323,618 / 60 * 96M / 221897388 = 2,446` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, innodb_log_file_size can be changed dynamically; I don't know about MariaDB. Be sure to also change my.cnf
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 100663296). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( default_tmp_storage_engine ) = default_tmp_storage_engine =`

`( ( Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written ) / Uptime / innodb_io_capacity ) = ( 64423401 + 516159 ) / 323618 / 200 = 100.3%` -- If > 100%, need more io_capacity.
-- Increase innodb_io_capacity (now 200) if the drives can handle it.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor. Limits write IO requests per second (IOPS).
-- For starters: HDD: 200; SSD: 2000.

`( innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit ) = 1` -- 1 = secure; 2 = faster
-- (You decide) Use 1, along with sync_binlog (now 0)=1 for the greatest level of fault tolerance. 0 is best for speed. 2 is a compromise between 0 and 1.

`( sync_binlog ) = 0` -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster. 0 is OK for Galera.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( Innodb_deadlocks ) = 12 / 323618 = 0.13 /HR` -- Deadlocks
-- SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; to see the latest pair of queries that deadlocked.

`( max_connections ) = 5,000` -- Maximum number of connections (threads). Impacts various allocations.
-- If max_connections (now 5000) is too high and various memory settings are high, you could run out of RAM.

`( 176000 * max_connections ) = (176000 * 5000) / 32768M = 2.6%` -- Estimate of ram usage due to the size of max_connections.
-- max_connections (now 5000) is somewhat high

`( character_set_client ) = character_set_client = latin1` --
-- If you will be using text from places other than Western Europe, consider switching to utf8mb4. (Beyond the scope of this discussion.)

`( character_set_connection ) = character_set_connection = latin1` --

`( character_set_results ) = character_set_results = latin1` --

`( log_warnings ) = log_warnings = 4`

`( (Com_show_create_table + Com_show_fields) / Questions ) = (311486 + 5530) / 9972190 = 3.2%` -- Naughty framework -- spending a lot of effort rediscovering the schema.
-- Complain to the 3rd party vendor.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( (Queries-Questions)/Queries ) = (70291592-9972190)/70291592 = 85.8%` -- Fraction of queries that are inside Stored Routines.
-- (Not bad if high; but it impacts the validity of some other conclusions.)

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Created_tmp_tables ) = 320,917 / 897316 = 35.8%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Maybe increase tmp_table_size (now 16777216) and max_heap_table_size (now 16777216); improve indexes; avoid blobs, etc.

`( Com_rollback / (Com_commit + Com_rollback) ) = 177 / (1706 + 177) = 9.4%` -- Rollback : Commit ratio
-- Rollbacks are costly; change app logic

`( Com_set_option / Com_select ) = 7,419,891 / 5512162 = 134.6%`
-- It seems 'wrong' to do more SETs than SELECTs.

`( Com__biggest ) = Com__biggest = Com_set_option` -- Which of the "Com_" metrics is biggest.
-- Normally it is Com_select (now 5512162). If something else, then it may be a sloppy platform, or may be something else.

`( log_slave_updates ) = log_slave_updates = OFF`
-- Galera needs log_slave_updates (now OFF) ON

`( wsrep_log_conflicts ) = wsrep_log_conflicts = OFF` -- If you get deadlock conflicts during COMMIT, this flag can be helpful.

`( long_query_time ) = 5` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( Max_used_connections / max_connections ) = 883 / 5000 = 17.7%` -- Peak % of connections
-- Since several memory factors can expand based on max_connections (now 5000), it is good not to have that setting too high.

`( Max_used_connections ) = 883` -- High-water mark for connections
-- Lots of inactive connections is OK; over 100 active connections is likely to be a problem. Max_used_connections (now 883) does not distinguish them; Threads_running (now 2) is instantaneous.

`( Max_used_connections / host_cache_size ) = 883 / 853 = 103.5%`
-- Increase host_cache_size (now 853)

`( Com_change_db / Connections ) = 1,636,449 / 56336 = 29` -- Database switches per connection
-- (minor) Consider using "db.table" syntax

`( Com_change_db ) = 1636449 / 323618 = 5.1 /sec` -- Probably comes from USE statements.
-- Consider connecting with DB, using db.tbl syntax, eliminating spurious USE statements, etc.

`( Aborted_clients / Connections ) = 19,273 / 56336 = 34.2%` -- Threads bumped due to timeout
-- Increase wait_timeout (now 600); be nice, use disconnect

`( thread_pool_max_threads ) = 65,536` -- One of many settings for MariaDB's thread pooling
-- Lower the value.

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

**Abnormally small:**

```
Acl_database_grants = 0
Aria_pagecache_blocks_unused = 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total = 8,064
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests = 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests / (Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests + Innodb_buffer_pool_reads ) = 0
Memory_used_initial = 17.2MB
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size = 2MB
wsrep_received_bytes = 0.21 /sec
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_call_procedure = 14 /sec
Com_create_procedure = 7.5 /HR
Com_create_temporary_table = 1 /sec
Com_create_trigger = 0.68 /HR
Com_create_view = 0.2 /HR
Com_dealloc_sql = 5.4 /sec
Com_drop_procedure = 7.5 /HR
Com_drop_temporary_table = 1.3 /sec
Com_drop_view = 0.2 /HR
Com_execute_sql = 5.4 /sec
Com_prepare_sql = 5.4 /sec
Com_release_savepoint = 6.9 /HR
Com_rollback_to_savepoint = 0.48 /sec
Com_savepoint = 6.9 /HR
Com_show_create_db = 6.9 /HR
Com_show_create_proc = 1.3 /sec
Com_show_create_trigger = 0.099 /sec
Com_show_function_status = 6.9 /HR
Com_show_open_tables = 0.13 /HR
Com_show_package_body_status = 6.9 /HR
Com_show_package_status = 6.9 /HR
Com_show_procedure_status = 6.9 /HR
Com_unlock_tables = 7.4 /HR
Executed_events = 0.044 /HR
Feature_trigger = 0.3 /sec
Feature_window_functions = 3.2 /HR
Handler_discover = 1.3 /HR
Handler_savepoint = 14 /HR
Handler_savepoint_rollback = 0.96 /sec
Innodb_background_log_sync = 1 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_lru_flushed = 513,049
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_lru_freed = 1.11e+7
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads * innodb_page_size / innodb_buffer_pool_size = 786418.5%
Innodb_deadlocks / Com_commit = 0.70%
Innodb_master_thread_idle_loops = 1 /sec
Memory_used = 23.4%
Open_streams = 4
Opened_views = 0.059 /sec
Performance_schema_digest_lost = 3.11e+6
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost = 43
Ssl_accepts = 56,323
Ssl_default_timeout = 7,200
Ssl_finished_accepts = 56,323
Ssl_verify_depth = 1.84e+19
Ssl_verify_mode = 5
Tc_log_page_size = 4,096
Threads_connected = 315
auto_increment_offset = 2
innodb_lru_scan_depth / innodb_io_capacity = 7.68
performance_schema_max_statement_classes = 222
wsrep_apply_oool = 0.0261
wsrep_cert_interval = 53,389
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
Slave_heartbeat_period = 0
Slave_received_heartbeats = 0
aria_recover_options = BACKUP,QUICK
character_set_system = utf8mb3
disconnect_on_expired_password = OFF
event_scheduler = ON
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
innodb_prefix_index_cluster_optimization = ON
old_alter_table = DEFAULT
old_mode = UTF8_IS_UTF8MB3
optimizer_trace = enabled=off
sql_slave_skip_counter = 0
wsrep_cluster_state_uuid = 7c7cbcd4-79c7-11ea-9591-26df36ace840
wsrep_cluster_status = Primary
wsrep_connected = ON
wsrep_provider = /usr/lib64/galera-4/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider_capabilities = :MULTI_MASTER:CERTIFICATION:PARALLEL_APPLYING:TRX_REPLAY:ISOLATION:PAUSE:CAUSAL_READS:INCREMENTAL_WRITESET:UNORDERED:PREORDERED:STREAMING:NBO:
wsrep_provider_name = Galera
wsrep_provider_vendor = Codership Oy 
wsrep_provider_version = 26.4.14(r06a0c28)
wsrep_ready = ON
wsrep_start_position = 7c7cbcd4-79c7-11ea-9591-26df36ace840:157630578
```

Comment: Wow a looong answer , but after "Recommended changes to settings:", you say: `table_open_cache = 800`, and after that you says (multiple times) to increase that value to 2000. So, the recommended change might be to set it to 2000, and not to 800 ?

Comment: @Luuk - It is _currently_ set to 2000.  I recommend a lower setting.  I have an automated analysis.  Alas, it is not polished enough to provide online.

Comment: OK, I must have misread/misinterpreted, but still confused why you recommend to lower the value, and the tool says (two times): `"May need to increase table_open_cache (now 2000)"`

Comment: @Luuk - Yeah, that is one of the contradictions that it can confuse people with.  The "misseses" and "overflows" imply that the number (2000) is not high enough.  Meanwhile, other things (such as memory usage) imply that it may be too high.  I'm deleting from "Most Important".